# Puppet Agent fails to run install.bash

Tags: puppet

I am having my CentOS 6.5 installed with Puppet Entrprise 3.3.

The dashboard is running fine.

Now I want to add a puppet agent on another CentOS 6.5 box.

Since both are same OS type, Following the guidelines available in puppet docs site https://docs.puppetlabs.com/pe/latest/install_agents.html, I run the following

```
curl -k https://<mymasterserverFQDN>:8140/packages/current/install.bash | sudo bash
```

But I receive the error

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (56) Received HTTP code 503 from proxy after CONNECT
```

I checked my master server iptables.I have added rule for 8140 port and did *sudo service iptables save*.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:8140 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

The supposed to be agent box can resolve the master server hostname, the ping responds properly.

I have tried to run curl by additionally providing the proxy address (using -x [protocol://proxy:port] (login credentials not needed), as I am actually behind proxy, but not sure how that will effect this installation here.
But no benefit.

Also tried with

```
curl -k https://<mymasterserverFQDN>:8140/packages/current/el-6-x86_64.bash | sudo bash
```

but no result.

I can see the install.bash/el-6-x86_64.bash exists /opt/puppet/packages/public/current in the master server [It was a standard monolitic installation, I did not do anything funky with it]

Can anyone please help me out on this. I searched in net but not getting much information on this error.

Reply/Update #1

Hi Zordache, 
Thanks for looking into.

I see the same error messege. I am trying to make use of wireshark/tcpdump to see if those tools help someway to understand the problem.

```
curl -k https://<mymasterserverFQDN>:8140/packages/current/el-6-x86_64.bash | sudo bash
% Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 0 
curl: (56) Received HTTP code 503 from proxy after CONNECT
```

I did not touch the install.bash. One thought though, I was playing with puppestmaster.conf file to make a different server as CA server. Can that effect the install.bash. My understanding was installation will create trouble but an agent run might cause down the line.

**UPDATE 2014-10-24**

The following command if I use, it runs fine.

```
sudo curl -k https://<mymasterserverFQDN>:8140/packages/current/el-6-x86_64.bash | sudo bash
```

Comment: If you run `curl -k https://<mymasterserverFQDN>:8140/packages/current/el-6-x86_64.bash`  all by itself, what do you see?  Hopefully the contents of your install script right?

Comment: Hi Zordache, Thanks for looking into. I see the same error messege. I am trying to make use of wireshark/tcpdump to see if those tools help someway to understand the problem. 

curl -k https://<mymasterserverFQDN>:8140/packages/current/el-6-x86_64.bash | sudo bash

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (56) Received HTTP code 503 from proxy after CONNECT

I did not touch the install.bash script

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the error.  Does your agent need to use a proxy to get to your puppet server?  Have you checked the lots on your proxy?  Have you checked the server logs on the puppet server?

Comment: I think it needs to go through the proxy. My proxies in .bashrc/curl/wget files are properly set and functional. I somehow doubting the firewall.  
When I run tcpdump on master server keeping eye on client's IP, during the curl command I do not see anything happening, neither the tcpdump in client's machine shows that it could contact master server. 
Though if I run `https://masterserverfqdn:8140` on browser it returns 

`The environment must be purely alphanumeric, not ''`

that I believe says the connection is good. can you please suggest which log in particular to look (I am bit new here)?

Comment: @Zoredache I think I have got a solution to this. Instead of 

`curl -k https://<mymasterserverFQDN>:8140/packages/current/el-6-x86_64.bash | sudo bash`
if I write 

`sudo curl -k https://<mymasterserverFQDN>:8140/packages/current/el-6-x86_64.bash | sudo bash`
it solves the problem.